# How to access Jenkins running on EC2 MAC instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-cli, aws-security-group

I have been working on Jenkins setup on AWS EC2 MAC instance. After installation of Jenkins on MAC instance, I'm able to access Jenkins from the MAC locally by giving 'localhost:8080'. But i'm unable to do the same on other web browsers by using 'instance Public IP:8080'. However, we were able to connect to the instance via SSH successfully.

Below are some of the solutions we have tried:

- Including the port 8080 in the AWS Security group.
- Ensured that the internet gateway modem is enabled with the instance.
- Further we tried to enable All Ports in the AWS Security group.
- Configured local system firewall settings and tried too.
- Added ICMP to the security group.
- Tried to configure MAC instance's firewall as well.

All these solutions hadn't worked out. Is there anything else I had missed implementing?

Answer (score 1):

How you have installed Jenkins on the MAC? If you are used homebrew to install Jenkins here is the answer:

If your Jenkins running through Homebrew,

Since the folder is a hidden folder on macOS. so you will need to do the following things to unhide the folder.

Open Macintosh HD in finder -> and **press cmd + shift + . (dot)**

This will reveal all hidden folders.

After you unhidden the folder, paste the below command in the terminal:

```
nano /usr/local/Cellar/jenkins-lts/2.xxx/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins-lts.plist
```

Change httpListenAddress **127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs$
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.mxcl.jenkins</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/bin/java</string>
      <string>-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true</string>
      <string>-jar</string>
      <string>/usr/local/opt/jenkins/libexec/jenkins.war</string>
      <string>--httpListenAddress=0.0.0.0</string>
      <string>--httpPort=8080</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Once the above steps are done, you can access the Jenkins using hostname or public IP address.